# Why do models of ZF which are not $\omega$-models have non-standard formulas whose length is "infinitely large natural numbers"?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, meta-math, nonstandard-models

In his popular book *Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs*, Kunen gives the following definitions on the bottom of page 145:

> Let $\mathcal{A} = \lbrace A, E \rbrace$ be a structure for the language of set theory. Let also $\mathcal{A} \models ZF$. We call $\mathcal{A}$ an $\omega$-model iff there is no $a \in A$ such that $\mathcal{A} \models “a \in \omega”$ but $a \neq n^{\mathcal{A}}$ for each $n$.

He then proceeds with the following assertion:

> If $\mathcal{A} \models ZF$, then for each formula $\phi$ in the metatheory, there is a corresponding $\phi^{\mathcal{A}} \in A$, where $\phi^{\mathcal{A}}$ is the interpretation of $\ulcorner\phi\urcorner$ in $\mathcal{A}$ (where $\ulcorner\phi\urcorner$ is a constant symbol—usually an element of $\omega^{< \omega}$—meant to represent $\phi$ in the language). If $\mathcal{A}$ is an $\omega$-model, then these are the only formulas of $\mathcal{A}$, but if $\mathcal{A}$ is not an $\omega$-model, then **$\mathcal{A}$ has non-standard formulas whose lengths are infinitely large natural numbers.**

Basically, I am trying to make sense of the statement in bold. First of all, is Kunen claiming that a non-$\omega$-model *may* contain non-standard formulas or that it will *necessarily* contain such formulas? If so, how can we reach that conclusion? It seems to me that even if $A$ has non-standard elements, we still have no way of knowing if $\phi^{\mathcal{A}}$ is or isn't a standard natural number of $A$, regardless of what formula $\phi$ we start with.

What am I missing? Some compactness argument perhaps?

**Bonus question:** What is "*a length of size equal to an infinitely large **natural** number*" in this context? I mean it's one think to talk about non-standard elements of a model, and a completely different one to associate these elements with "size" in the metatheory. How do these non-standard formulas look-like?

Comment: It seems like your main issue is that you do not have a definition of what "formula of $\mathcal{A}$" means.  Without such a definition you cannot possibly say anything about such formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole "point", one might say, of an $\omega$-model is that its natural numbers only consist of the "standard" natural numbers. Since pretty much by definition, any model of ZFC must contain a set that it would "call" as "$\mathbb{N}$", we can inquire as to the contents of this set and whether or not they are only the "standard" natural numbers or, whether or not that they also include nonstandard numbers. $\omega$-models' "$\mathbb{N}$"s only include standard natural numbers.

So if we are *not* in an $\omega$-model, then that means that the model's "$\mathbb{N}$" *must* contain some *non*-standard numbers. Where that translates to non-standard *formulas* is that "formulas" are also an object we can formulate within the set theory and thus *also* can undergo "promotion" via the transfer principle. To see this, note that (as just one of an endless number of possible ways), we can encode a formula as a specific kind of function from a natural number to $\{ 0, 1 \}$ or better, in purely set-theoretic terms, to $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$, where the interpretation of such a function is that it indexes the bits of the formula when its graphic symbols are encoded in some kind of binary-based encoding, say, something like ASCII or UNICODE, and then taking that to be a string of binary bits (0 or 1).

But note now: *because we have non-standard numbers, we can now have some formula-like objects which are functions with domain a nonstandard number.* Such things are formulas of nonstandard length. Moreover, if it did *not* contain such formulas, that would mean it would have naturals, that it would recognize as such, and yet that would not be able to map out to $\{0, 1\}$ in ways that ZFC says can happen, and so such a model would fail to be a model of ZFC.

Finally, what does such a formula "look" like, as like a visualization? Well, imagine an infinitely long trail of logical symbols like you'd usually think, e.g.

$$\neg(A \vee [B \wedge C] \wedge \neg(\neg A) \vee \cdots$$

trailing off *forever*, but then also, somewhere "out there in the hazy mist of the foggy borderland between the definitively finite and definitively infinite", you can dream off to other strigns of symbols...

$$\cdots \vee A \vee A \vee A \vee [\neg A] \wedge B \wedge \cdots$$

where it continues now bidirectionally on both sides and, just as how a nonstandard natural looks, there's a dense linecloud-collection of these doubly-open-ended infinite chains. However, the model, just as it cannot see the nonstandard naturals are nonstandard, also can't see that this strange thing is not a formula. The symbols (or better, the bits in the encoding) will be indexed purely by nonstandard numbers, e.g. $\neg$ above will be located at, say, $(\mbox{some infinitely big 'root'}) - 6000^{\mathrm{googolplex}^\mathrm{moser}}$. And, of course, the formula must be generable by some procedure that could be carried out in ordinary ZFC, and extended to the nonstandard length.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. So is the "key" that if $A$ contains a nonstandard number $a$, then it will also interpret $\omega^{< \omega}$ differently than an $\omega$-model? By that I mean that now $\mathcal{A}$ "thinks" that the function $a \rightarrow \omega$ is just another finite sequence of strings and thus it must correspond to yet another "normal" formula $\phi$. In reality, outside of $\mathcal{A}$, $a$ is some infinite ordinal, thus preventing $\phi$ from being a formula. Like ordinals, the larger $a$ gets, the "weirder" $\phi$ gets. Am I thinking about this right?

Comment: @Pellenthor : Absolutely - these same considerations apply to ordinal numbers, too. Non-$\omega$ ZFC models will also contain "non-standard ordinals" that are strictly between all the standard finite ordinals and $\omega$, and have the same order structure as the non-standard "$\mathbb{N}$". And this will also mean the class of ordinals will not be well-ordered "from outside", but it will "think" it is "from inside" and so its "idea" of what a well-order is will also differ from what yours may be.

Comment: Though I should caution that with one point I just saw: $a$ will not be an infinite ordinal outside the model $\mathcal{A}$. It will be some non-archimedean ill-ordered number. This is because the set of "ordinals" in the model will _not_ be externally well-ordered any more than $\mathbb{N}$ is. The "ordinals" will still satisfy the initial-segment property that if $\beta$ is an $\mathcal{A}$-ordinal with $\beta < \alpha$ then $\beta \subset \alpha$, but won't be externally well-ordered under this ordering.

Comment: The tension is solved because we can extrospect that there are some initial segments which are not supped by any $\beta$, such as the standard naturals themselves, but $\mathcal{A}$ cannot introspect those: it does not feature them as sets to begin with. There is a ${"\mathbb{N}"} \in \mathcal{A}$, but $\mathbb{N} \notin \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: This is very interesting @The_Sympathizer, thank you! I was also concerned myself, because you mentioned "bidirectionality" which is not something ordinals satisfy. Intuitively, it sounds like - and please correct me if I am wrong -  we can apply a simple compactness argument to show that there is an infinite decreasing sequence above $\mathbb{N}$, to "violate" well-orderness from the outside. Incidentally, would you happen to have any study references to non-archimedean ill-ordered numbers that goes a bit deeper on the concept?

Answer (score 8):

For every natural $n$, $\phi_n$ is a sentence, where $\phi_0$ is $\forall x\,(x=x)$ and $\phi_{n+1}$ is $(\phi_n\land\phi_n)$. By recursion, there is a sentence in the theory that codes this claim and so, for any model, for any $n$ that, from the point of view of the model, is a natural number, there is an object of the model that the model interprets as the sentence $\phi_n$. This holds even if $n$ is nonstandard.

Of course, if $n$ is nonstandard, this object $\phi_n$ is not *really* a formula, but the model cannot see that.

Comment: This is very useful thanks. Just to make sure I fully understand this: If $a$ is non-standard, would that make $\phi_a$ be "$a$ copies" of $\phi_0$?

Comment: Yes, from the point of view of the model, that's what $\phi_a$ is.

Comment: Pellenthor, $2^{\alpha}$ copies, actually. (That's gonna be **WEERD!**) Note that it doubles up each iteration. If you want $\alpha+1$ copies, take $\phi_{n+1} = \phi_n \wedge \phi_0$, which just appends one $\phi_0$ each increment instead of doubling up the string each increment. (If you want $\alpha$ copies, rename $\phi_0$ to $\phi_1$ :) )

Comment: Good catch @The_Sympathizer! I was indeed considering the "linear" case for some reason. Perhaps in an attempt to not miss the forest for the trees... :) But you are of course correct!